# Find dependant (reverse dependencies) in maven project

Tags: maven, dependencies

I'm trying to find a command that does the opposite of `mvn dependency:tree`. I want to find out all the projects that depend on a specific module. As trivial as it may sound, I couldn't find such thing.

The use case is in order to find, in a very large project, if I can delete a module or if there are other modules that use it as their dependency.

Comment: That does not sound trivial at all.  How could this be possible?  I *hope* maven doesn't tell you what dependencies my project is using.

Comment: @tieTYT -I'm talking about modules in the same project of course. Not talking about a lib I wrote and published in a central repository and projects around the world use.

I'm talking about the same project - the same pom.xml parent.

Comment: Edit the pom file to change the module's name (not refactor, edit), and see what breaks...

Comment: @EngineerDollery - That's a great approach (surely better than deleting it and see what breaks that I though of at the beginning :) ).
I was kinda hoping there was something more structured though.

Comment: In intellij you could highlight the module and hit alt-f7 (search for usage)

Comment: @EngineerDollery - It doesn't seem to work on the module level. Only for classes/methods/etc... (and I'm even using the premium edition)

Comment: You could generate a uml diagram of your system and review the afferent's visually

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=module
```

Where `module` is the dependency you're interested in. You should get the list of libraries that depend on the module you've specified, either directly or transitively.

Answer (score 1):

Although outdated since the question is from 2014, I was looking for something similar:

matching dependencies (f.e. `junit`) to a list of projects (f.e. `maven-compiler-plugin 3.6.0`) in use, which should give a list of dependent dependencies currently in use (f.e. `junit 4.12`). That should point us (for our own projects) to outdated dependencies (f.e. `junit 3.8`). This will be used for the undeployment of overgrown services (in this case).

Since I was unable to find an automated version (other than manual nexus/repo-plugins or maven-dependency-greps), I wrote a small java tool: [reverseDependencies](https://github.com/seywerth/reverseDependencies). Feel free to use if you come across a similar task. **Note:** it will check against the online Nexus-like repository or cache file that you specify.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that is not part of Maven. But it can be implemented in Maven repositories like Nexus and Bintray. The closest I've found is in Bintray and its [Build Integration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration).

But since my clients are using different Maven repositories I needed something that works for any repository. So I created [Pom Dependency Analyzer Web](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/pom-dependency-analyzer-web) that can keep track of **dependents**, and **dependencies**.

[image: Dependents and dependencies]