# List all the modules of an aggregate POM dependent on a specific dependency

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

Here's my aggregate POM:

```
<project>
  ...
  <groupId>myAggregate</groupId>
  <artifactId>myAggregate</artifactId>
  ...

  <modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
    <module>module4</module>
    <module>module5</module>
  </modules>

  ...
</project>
```

Assume that the modules: `module1`, `module3` and `module5` depend on same/different versions of an artifact, say, `dependency1`. I wanted the `maven-dependency-plugin` to list these modules when I run a goal on the aggregate POM above, but I couldn't find a goal that would do it for me. Like, for example:

`mvn dependency:dependents-of -Dartifact=...`

Anyone know of any plugin that tells me this or if I should write my own goal for the plugin?

Comment: There is a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809783/find-dependant-reverse-dependencies-in-maven-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `modules` were right under the `aggregator`, I merely used `grep` on the `pom.xml`s to list them. Sometimes, simplicity helps ;)